# iOS 9 UIAlertView now deprecated and replaced by UIAlertController, how to show it on UIView, as view does not have method presentViewController

Tags: ios, uitableview, uialertcontroller

I don't know whether this question is asked before but I am not able to find this one.

With **iOS 9 UIAlertView is deprecated** and we have to use `UIAlertController`, now as it is controller and not view any more we have to present it on some other controller.

So my question here is what if I have a `UITableViewCell` which has a `UIButton` and on its action I want to show alert in this case `self` will not have method `presentViewController` as it is `UITableViewCell` in that case how can we show the alert.

I know I can do it by delegate but, why should I add a delegate logic just to show informative message.

Comment: I agree with everyone that says that the controller must stay in charge of presenting the alert. But if you want to keep the logic in the cell, you can add a weak delegate to your cell that you will set with your controller when setting up the cell.

Comment: @deadbeef thats what was my last statement, why should I add weak delegate just to show an informative message. I hope now no one disagrees that alerts can be also be shown for informative messages!

Comment: Because that's the way [MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model–view–controller) works and UIKit is built with MVC in mind, and using it differently is always going to be a pain for you. With MVC, controllers manage everything that gets presented onscreen, views don't do squat, they just show the stuff they were told to show, period.

Comment: Note that there are many other ways than MVC to build an application. It's just because UIKit was build that way, we as developper don't really have a choice. If you're unhappy with it just go back to 2007 and tell Steve he just have the worst idea of his life...

Comment: @deadbeef I hope I could have meat Steve :) he is my idol, making no offence to any one and partially agreeing to you, being a developer I work with free mind and can make or ask for changes even in existing system that's what my Job is and thats what I love doing.

Comment: just being correct, the `UIAlertView` has been deprecated in iOS8 actually, about a year ago...

Answer (score 3):

The view should not present the alert. Have the controller that owns the view do it.

Remember [MVC](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MVC.html).

The controller should react to the button press, figure out which cell sent it and present the appropriate alert.

Comment: That sounds good, in theory, and is certainly the "pure" approach.  It is not, however, always a pragmatic approach.  For example, I have an app with a cell that displays a map.  I feel it's better to keep the logic contained in the cell, rather than farm it out to a host view controller.  If the cell is used in multiple view controllers, the permissions and other alerts would need to be duplicated in some fashion.

Comment: I know that, but what if I have a prototype cell, and it has a UIButton on it the action is inside the UITableViewCell class now the self will not have presentViewController method as it is UITableView Cell?

Comment: @Avi Sorry, but an alert presented on top of the view controller is *never* business of a subview.

Comment: @Avi thanks you got my question, who the hell has voted down the question it is a simple and valid question?

Comment: That is purely a matter of opinion.

Comment: @Avi Absolutely not. Please read the MVC reference I put into my answer.

Comment: @Mundi, MVC is a design pattern; it is not a law.

Comment: @Avi, of course you are right. I am not dogmatic about this. However, in this particular case it strikes me as completely irresponsible to have a table view cell present an alert. This will result in code that can break any time. All proposed solutions require some kind of coupling with the controller, so that the goal of encapsulation is anyway not achieved.

Comment: Encapsulation is maintained by the the alert actions being defined within the cell's class.  In any event, the poster was already aware of the delegate pattern, and was asking for alternatives.  There are always pros and cons to any competing designs, and knowing the alternatives can help one choose correctly for the scenario at hand.

Comment: you could use protocols implemented by view controller.

Comment: @Mundi I have already stated that I can add delegate and can find a cell and show an alert on my view controller, here the question from the beginning was why should I use delegate or even notification pattern just to show an informative message, hope you understand now, I agree that delegation in other cases will be the wright way, if we have to do some action or complex logic on that button click on a particular cell.

Comment: Having the controller handle the click of the button is *not* a "delegate pattern".

Answer (score -1):

As you alluded to, there are many ways to solve this.  One approach I've taken is to add a weak reference to the view controller as a property of the cell.

Comment: Bad idea. The cell should not be responsible for presenting alerts!

Comment: When it comes down to choosing between separation of concerns (MVC) and encapsulation, I lean towards encapsulation.  I find that it will lead to more maintainable code in the long run.  The way I look at it is that the alerts are part of the (sub)view.  It just so happens that the API requires going outside of the view to get things done, but that's just an unfortunate accident.

Comment: When the cell happens to be on an iPad in a popover, everything breaks. In this case, the alert should most probably be presented differently. This illustrates that it this approach is problematic.

Comment: True.  In such a situation, it would be better to use a delegate.

Answer (score -1):

Ideally View controller should be the responsible for showing alert...

You can simply create a weak reference of your UIViewController inside Cell's class and show Alert from cell class itself

Comment: Bad idea for the reasons outlined in the discussion.